# What does "otherwise than" mean in this text?

Tags: meaning

> Indeed, it cost an effort to picture him **otherwise than** bent over a desk, studiously revising the tariff of the town baths or gathering for a junior secretary the materials of a report on the new garbage-collection tax.

What does "otherwise than" mean in this context?

Comment: **Otherwise than** is, to me, an unusual way of saying **other than**. It's fine (and that's what it means), but the specific phrase *otherwise than* (not *otherwise* itself) is somewhat dated and not normally used anymore.

Comment: In any other way than...